# SearchView in appbar does not take query

Tags: java, android

I just started with developing an app and encounter the following. I'm stuck.

When I press on the SearchView in the appbar on my phone the SearchView simply closes. It does not take any query and I can't find out what I did wrong.

The code from the .java file where the SearchView is in the appbar:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ik_bied_aan);
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.xml.options_menu, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    return true;
}

}
```

The manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SearchableActivity"
                android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

The SearchableActivity.java file:

```
public class SearchableActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        doMySearch(query);
        //use the query to search your data somehow
    }
}

private void doMySearch(String query) {


}
```

}

Thank you in advance for your time.

EDIT:

The logs after pressing multiple times on the SearchView appbar:

```
2019-02-20 16:46:05.958 8141-8163/com.example.android.zwapperr 
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7a9e579200 
(MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView) with handle 0x7a9e6995c0


2019-02-20 16:46:24.317 8141-8148/com.example.android.zwapperr 
I/ndroid.zwapper: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void 
android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, 
android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)

2019-02-20 16:46:25.492 8141-8163/com.example.android.zwapperr 
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7a9e5d0900 
(MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView) with handle 0x7a9e699600

2019-02-20 16:46:39.643 8141-8163/com.example.android.zwapperr 
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7a9e5f5000 
(MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView) with handle 0x7a9e5095a0
```

Comment: please post the log

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: This doen't look like  exception. Exception mostly in red color . Ex https://www.google.com/search?q=logcat+android+studio&safe=strict&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCwMnK1srgAhVYfysKHXOfAwUQ_AUIDigB&biw=1299&bih=669#imgrc=rFdjUXA898hJ8M:

Comment: what exactly do you mean? Do I have to look for an exception? This is what is logged if I press on the searchview

Comment: @Peter yes, because this doesn't looked like an exception.Can you print screen the log instead ?

Comment: [picture is in the link. Is this what you are looking for?][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyqdp.png